# Ошибка "user-defined type not defined error" при запуске макроса в Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

В Outlook имеется макрос, который открывает ссылку из письма в Chrome и IE. Этот макрос отлично работал, но после переустановки Windows 10 и Outlook 2016 перестал (я скопировал текст макроса через блокнот). При запуске макроса появляется сообщение "Compile error: user-defined type not defined error". На форумах пишут, что такое бывает, если не включена "библиотека".

Кто-нибудь знает, как заставить работать этот макрос?

```
Public Sub OpenLinks(olMail As Outlook.MailItem)

     Dim Reg1 As RegExp
     Dim M1 As MatchCollection
     Dim M As Match
     Dim strURL As String
     Dim oApp As Object
    Set oApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    Set Reg1 = New RegExp

    With Reg1
     .Pattern = "(https://example.com)"
     .Global = True
     .IgnoreCase = True
     End With

    If Reg1.Test(olMail.Body) Then

    Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(olMail.Body)
     For Each M In M1
       strURL = M.SubMatches(0)
       Debug.Print strURL

     Shell """" & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" & """" & " -new-tab " & strURL

    'wait for page to load before passing the web URL
      Do While oApp.Busy
      DoEvents
      Loop

    oApp.navigate strURL
    oApp.Visible = True

      Next
      End If

    Set Reg1 = Nothing
    Set oApp = Nothing

     End Sub
    'The following is a stub macro for testing the run a script rule without the need to send messages to trigger . Select a message and run the RunScript macro.

    Sub RunScript()
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objItem As MailItem
    Set objApp = Application
    Set objItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

    'macro name you want to run goes here
    OpenLinks objItem

    End Sub
```

Comment: А на какой строке кода возникает ошибка, нам предлагается угадать?

Comment: При ошибке выделяется строка Dim Reg1 As RegExp

Comment: Ну так подключите референсную библиотеку-то... фамилия её "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions x.xx".

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь ошибка "Compile error: Method or data member not found" в строке strURL = M.SubMatches(0) (выделено SubMatches) Поскажите, пожалуйста, что с этим делать?